# How to use Anylogic Database Query tool to insert table values in code

Tags: anylogic

I have recently started using AnyLogic 7.3. I am trying to use the "Insert database query" tool inside AnyLogic in order to insert values from a database table I have created in AnyLogic. 
 The table I created has many values and I would like to insert each time a certain value from column2 based on the value of column 1 which is constantly changing until the loop is satisfied.

I would like Anylogic to choose and insert the value in column 2 from the database  given that the value in column 1  is equal to xx ( which is a variable having a certain value in the function). Finally I would like to assign the value to "probOfWin". xx is always changing since it is inside a loop.

In the "Insert database query" tool I am selecting the table name "prob low bid" then choosing column2 "n_3" for Value column. For choice condition I am selecting Column1 "x" then choosing equals and typing "xx" which is a variable in the code function. This is the code that is generated by Anylogic inside the for loop.

```
    probOfWin = (double) selectFrom(prob_low_bid)
        .where(prob_low_bid.x.eq(xx))
       .firstResult(prob_low_bid.n_3); 
    }
```

Thank you

Comment: looks good to me. What is the problem, actually? :-)

Comment: These statements are nested in a for loop.                                                 Whenever I build the model I have no problems but when I run the model errors pop up and this code statement is highlighted :                     .firstResult(prob_low_bid.n_3);

Comment: what is the error? ;-)